# Why do I need the cordova.js file when I can't find it in my www folder?

Tags: cordova

My Ionic app is to take photo using native cordova plugin which works fine if i include cordova.js script tag in index.html. But i dont have any cordova.js file in my project. How it works?

If i remove that script tag, then my code fails.

//This line

Comment: <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

The `cordova.js` file gets copied into the www directory structure when the app is compiled, you don't need to manually copy it - you just add the link to it in your head